# How to execute a program in compatibility mode from code?

Tags: c#, compatibility, windows-server-2008-r2

**Environment:** *Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit*

I have a program that works with *Windows Server 2003 SP1* **compatibility mode**. However, when I try to execute this program using C#, the program errors out.

I think it is because it is not running in compatibility mode when invoked from another program. I use `Process.Start(pathToExe)` from my code to start this program.

I tried to run the calling program in compatibility mode to check if this would make the program run correctly.

Please note that I have set the program set to compatibility from **Properties | Compatibility**.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understand your problem exactly, but if you want to run the Program always in the Compatibility mode you can set the registry to make it work so.

**Registry Key:**

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

Add a new String entry with,
**Name** : Your Application Path in Full.
**Type**: REG_SZ
**Data** : Required Compat Value. I think it is `WIN2003` OR `WIN2003SP1` in your case.

`Example:`
C:\Program Files\System32\Notepad.exe          REG_SZ          WIN2003

You can check for the current OS version you are running under and you can set and unset this registry value before calling the program.

Comment: It will probably work anyway but usually there is a tilde `~` at the beginning followed with space. Like `~ WIN2003`. Src: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15523-change-compatibility-mode-settings-apps-windows-10-a.html Chapter `To Manually Change Compatibility Mode Settings for an App in Registry Editor` fifth point