# C# set compatibility settings through code

Tags: c#, compatibility

I'm making a C# launcher for a program and I want it to be able to change the compatibility settings of the launched file, such as disabling display scaling on high dpi settings and setting the compatibility mode windows version.

Is it possible through C# code? If not, is it possible in C++?

Comment: I think it's only possible by setting it in the registry... something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249263/how-to-execute-a-program-in-compatibility-mode-from-code

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, however I still hope there is way to do it through code instead of editing the registry for the file I'm running :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is only a partial answer but it seems that certain compatibility settings such **Disable display scaling on high DPI settings** can be configured by using the `SetProcessDPIAware` function in the [WINAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633543(VS.85).aspx).

The documentation says **this can also be configured in the application (.exe) manifest and it is the recommended approach**.

Comment: This is a partial answer as it is only a solution for one of the compatibility settings (though the documentation might list the others) and I have not included a working example as I have not tried it myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the settings in an XML or JSON file and the C# launcher will change those settings. Then these JSON or XML settings can be read by any program written in any language. You can also encrypt them if you want extra safety.